# IOS7 Mapkit callout: image expected format has changed?

Tags: ios, mapkit, ios7, callout

In `mapkit` callouts, we have the possibility to add images to the left and right accessories of callout.

In `IOS7`, if those accessories are buttons, it seems that the expected format is the same as for `toolbar` or `tab bar` buttons. The picture below shows the difference between `IOS6` and `IOS7`.

[link to image](http://www.dechorgnat.com/documents/callout_difference.jpg)

Does anyone know how to keep the same behavior in `IOS7`?

Changing the button type does not help:

for example, `UIButtonTypeCustom` does not show image at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IOS 7 you have to use the new routine to re-render your image as the original otherwise it just uses it as a template giving you blue blobs as you can see in your pics ... here is the call.

```
    image = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```